# ESLint Typescript not picking up module declarations

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv

To use that properly, I've got this module declaration:

```
declare module '@env' {
  export const SOME_VAR: any;
}
```

Imported as follows:

```
import { SOME_VAR } from '@env';
```

ESLint keeps throwing one of these when I import it, though:

`ESLint: Unable to resolve path to module '@env'.(import/no-unresolved)`

I haven't been able to figure out why. Here's the `.eslintrc.js`

```
module.exports = {
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: 'tsconfig.json',
  },
  plugins: ['react'],
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'prettier',
    'plugin:prettier/recommended',
    'plugin:import/errors',
    'plugin:import/warnings',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
  ],
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
  },
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly',
  },
  ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js', 'src/generated/*'],
  rules: {
    'prettier/prettier': 'error',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    'import/extensions': [
      'error',
      'ignorePackages',
      {
        js: 'never',
        jsx: 'never',
        ts: 'never',
        tsx: 'never',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: `react-native-dotenv` maintainer here. Can you make sure your babel config has `react-native-dotenv` in the `plugins` list?